# <Cmd> doesn't seem to work in visual mode

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, visual-mode

The following command copies the selected text into the PRIMARY selection:

```
vnoremap <Leader>c :'<,'>!xsel<CR>u
```

But this way it doesn't work:

```
vnoremap <Leader>c <Cmd>'<,'>!xsel<CR>u
```

[The documentation](https://neovim.io/doc/user/map.html#%3CCmd%3E) says `<Cmd>` is generally preferable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From what I understand from the doc `<Cmd>` is useful to avoid using `:<C-u>` to remove the range in your mappings so here I don't thing using `<Cmd>` is useful for you since you want to keep the `'<,'>` range. If I try `vnoremap <Leader>c <Cmd>!xsel<CR>` on my setup the mapping works. Also it is probable that you want to use `xmap` instead of `vmap` for your mapping.

Comment: I'm not sure how can `vnoremap <Leader>c <Cmd>!xsel<CR>` work for you. From me it stays in visual mode, and nothing gets copied into the PRIMARY selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automatic bookmarks `'<` and `'>` get updated only after the Visual mode is left. Hence `<Cmd>` is not useful for your example, as you effectively apply the previous selection range, not the current one.

You really should use "normal colon"-mapping here:

```
xnoremap <Leader>c :w !xsel<CR>
```

Note (1) use `xnoremap` instead of `vnoremap` so we don't mess with "Select" modes; (2) don't add "Visual" marks, as they are put in automatically; (3) do `:w !xsel` to have stdin redirected only, as we don't need xsel's output.

Also note that Neovim is normally able to find xsel/xclip and to set up "plus" and "star" registers without any additional scripting (see `:h clipboard-tool`).